# ngClass doesn't apply style from .scss using binding

Tags: angular, input, angular-material

My issue is with the **sm-input-text.component**, it doesn't apply the style from **page-input-text.component.scss** using bind **[cssClass]** Input.
But the value is in there.

i have 2 components:

```
- sm-input-text.component.html
- sm-input-text.component.ts
- sm-input-text.component.scss
- page-input-text.component.html
- page-input-text.component.ts
- page-input-text.component.scss
```

my code is below:

```
sm-input-text.component.html:
i bind the [ngClass] <-> cssClass

    <mat-form-field [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <input
        matInput
        type="text"
        [placeholder]="placeholder"
        [formControlName]="fControlName"
        (input)="onInput($event)"

        [ngClass]="cssClass"
      >
    </mat-form-field>

page-input-text.component.html: i give value to the [cssClass]

    <form [formGroup]="formGroupOnlyOne">
        <sm-input-text
          #input1
          [formGroup]="formGroupOnlyOne"
          fControlName="input1"
          placeholder="InputText"

          [cssClass]="'no-selectable'"
        ></sm-input-text>
    </form>

page-input-text.component.scss:

    .no-selectable {
        cursor: auto;
        background: red;
    }
```

It doesn't apply. Yet if I add the 'no-selectable' style to the **sm-input-text.component.scss** then it is applied and shows it! 
I want to add style only on **matInput** from the **page-input-text.component.**
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Angular has **View Encapsulation**, you can't add CSS style class of child to parent unless both of it's encapsulation is set to `ViewEncapsulation.None`. You should add this class either in `sm-input-text.component.scss`. or you can add it globally in your styles.scss

**styles.scss**

```
.no-selectable {
    cursor: auto;
    background: red;
}
```

Whenever angular renders a component, it alters your css to match it with that component alone using a generated attribute selector in your css

for example

```
.no-selectable[ng-content23] {
    cursor: auto;
    background: red;
}
```

If you want to solve your issue, you can set your components encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <span class="red">Shadow DOM Rocks!</span>
  `,
  styles: [`
    :host {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    h1 {
      color: blue;
    }
    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }

  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
class MyApp {
}
```

You should set `ViewEncapsulation.None` to both **sm-input-text.component.ts, page-input-text.component.ts**

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you! I tried it out both the Encapsulation and the global styles and really the style shows in my browser but still it is no working. I think there is something mat-form-field issue. For example: if i give the [cssClass] Input to the mat-form-field then its ok, but if i give it to the matInput then it is no working, something override it?

Comment: Please check matinput api in angular material there's surely a way to add class

Comment: Instead of using `[ngClass]="cssClass"` use `[class]="cssClass"`

Comment: I checked the docs, yes you can add css in mat form field. If you add it to mat input, they are override it with their material styles.